# Computing a limit of nested variables

Tags: limits

I need to compute a limit as a part of my assignment, but I can't seem to figure out how to compute the expression.

The limit that needs to be computed is:

$$\text{For } 0<c<1, \lim_{n→ \infty} \frac{1}{n(1-\frac{c\ln(n)}{n})^{n-1}}$$

I tried using wolfromalpha, but I don't understand the result it's giving me.

I thought the result would be $\infty$, but it seems that the value of the limit depends on $c$, which I don't understand.

Computation from wolframalpha gave me $0$ for small c, and $\infty$ for $c>e$.

Comment: Interesting-looking limit. Did you try the "usual": taking the log then using l'Hospital's rule?

Comment: I did try, but it seems to me that the limit is going for 0 regardless of c.

Comment: ** I mean infinity